# MVC model regex validation disallow or exclude a certain character

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc

I have an mvc form page written in c#, when someone enters in a name for a product the name cannot have an underscore _ anywhere within it. I thought the regex for this would be pretty straightforward and currently have

```
[RegularExpression(@"[^\_]", ErrorMessage = "Underscores are not allowed in product names.")]
```

But the form page doesnt even load at all and gives this error

```
Additional information: parsing "[^\_]" - Unrecognized escape sequence \_.
```

So I kind of have two questions, is this regex properly formatted (obviously no, but how do I fix it?) and is this the regex that would give me the desired result?

Comment: why dont you use `[^_]*` ?

Comment: That fixed the problem and everything works perfectly. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not required to escape the underscore. Use the regex

```
^[^_]*$
```

it matches all strings without an underscore

See how the regex matches http://regex101.com/r/yN4kO7/1